# After using strtok then using strcmp to compare string is always false

Tags: c

I am new to c, and when reading from stdin I need to separate the words if there is a space. When I type exit I want to print hi but when I use strcmp it always returns false and doesn't print out hi

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 1024
int main()
{
    int n;
    char buffer [BUFFSIZE];
    int pos =0;
    char * parse ;
    char * buf [BUFFSIZE];
    read (STDIN_FILENO, buffer, BUFFSIZE);
    

    parse = strtok(buffer, " ");
    while (parse != NULL) {
        buf[pos] = parse;
        pos++;
    //printf( "%s\n", parse );
        parse = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    for (int i=0; i<pos; i++) {
        if (strcmp(buf[i], "exit") ==0) {
            printf("hi");
        }
        printf("%s\n",buf[i]);
    }
    

} // main
```

Comment: The arguments to `strtok` should be `" \t\r\n"`. You are not doing anything with `parse`?

Comment: The `read()` function (system call) does not thanks terminate its input.  Therefore, you.mustvdo so before calling `strtok()`.

Comment: What do you type as input?

Comment: Don't forget that `strcmp()` returns zero when the strings are equal.

Comment: Since you're using `read()`, you get `"exit\n"` at minimum as the input and because you're splitting only on blanks, not a more general white space string, this does not equal `"exit"`.  Print the data you are comparing — for example `printf("[[%sd]]\n", buf[i]);`.  The double square brackets help delimit the value in `buf[i]`.  This would show the problem.  You also need to null terminate the input.  `n = read(…); buf[n] = '\0';` (after checking that `n` is neither negative nor zero — those indicate an error or EOF respectively).

Answer (score 1):

There are several changes you need to make, mostly highlighted in the comments.

1. You need to ensure that the string is null-terminated before you pass it to `strtok()`.
2. You need to ensure that you split on at least blank and newline, and probably tab and carriage return too.

You should also check that the `read()` worked and returned data.

Those changes lead to something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 1024
#define DELIMITERS " \n\t\r"

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[BUFFSIZE + 1];  /* Allow for a null terminator */
    int pos = 0;
    char *parse;
    char *buf[BUFFSIZE];
    int nbytes = read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, BUFFSIZE);
    if (nbytes <= 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read anything from standard input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    buffer[nbytes] = '\0';

    parse = strtok(buffer, DELIMITERS);
    while (parse != NULL)
    {
        printf("parse [%s]\n", parse);
        buf[pos] = parse;
        pos++;
        parse = strtok(NULL, DELIMITERS);
    }
    printf("pos = %d\n", pos);
    for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(buf[i], "exit") == 0)
        {
            printf("found '%s' at index %d\n", buf[i], i);
        }
        printf("%s\n", buf[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

That includes some diagnostic printing.  Note that the message `hi` is singularly uninformative, especially as the message did not end with a newline.  End messages with newlines at minimum.

With the more extensive delimiters shown, the output looks like:

```
parse [exit]
pos = 1
found 'exit' at index 0
exit
```

With just blank as a delimiter, the output looked like:

```
parse [exit
]
pos = 1
exit
```

Note the extra blank line after `exit`.

With a more extensive input string `in due course, the keyword exit will be recognized.`, the output is:

```
parse [in]
parse [due]
parse [course,]
parse [the]
parse [keyword]
parse [exit]
parse [will]
parse [be]
parse [recognized.]
pos = 9
in
due
course,
the
keyword
found 'exit' at index 5
exit
will
be
recognized.
```

You decide if that's satisfactory.  I think the loop should probably end when the match is detected.